# Размножить таблицу

Tags: sql-server

Кто знает как?

Из таблицы:

---

```
Table1
Field1 Field2
  1      1---
  2      2---
  3      3---
  ...
```

Сделать таблицу:

---

```
Table1                 Table1
Field1 Field2          Field1 Field2 
  1      1---            1      1---
  2      2---    <->     2      2---
  3      3---            3      3---
  ...                    ...
```

Что бы получилось таблица:

---

```
Table1_1
Field1 Field2
  1      1---
  1      2---
  1      3---
  ...
  2      1---
  2      2---
  2      3---
  ...
  3      1---
  3      2---
  3      3---
  ...
```

Без курсоров!!!
Надо запросом если есть такая возможность.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял логики, по которой выбираются строки в эту таблицу - нужно чтобы field1 и field2 совпадало?

```
WITH t(field1) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Field1 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE field1 = field2
)

SELECT *
FROM t t1
CROSS JOIN t t2
```

Comment: Работает спасибо!!!

Comment: Был такой голландский математик Брауэр - основоположник интуиционизма. Он писал свои работы по-голландски и когда его работы переводили на английский, то обязательно делали приписку - мол что Брауэр действительно имел в виду - фиг знает, а я (переводчик), понял вот так.
Вот и тут я понял так, а что вы действительно имели в виду - не знаю

Comment: Field1 и Field2 не должны совподать, но ваш ответ работает для моей задачи